# Disable automatic saving in Datasheet view

Tags: datasheet, save

In the datasheet view of our list, if someone modifies a cell and then clicks into another one, changes are automatically saved. And you cannot "undo" them.

Would there be a solution to deactivate the automatic saving or a way to undo a change that has been saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sharepoint 2007 ,there is an undo.There is little bar on the right hand side of the view. If you click on it, you’ll get various options which you can take based on the list.

http://sympmarc.com/2010/09/20/sharepoints-datasheet-view-has-an-undo/

http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2010/03/15/datasheet-view-extras-who-knew.aspx

Comment: Many thanks, I did not know it but now I can see it. Yet as said above, the issue is that this undo cannot be used if the change was automatically saved. Meaning if you change of cell you only have a few seconds to undo then it is too late...

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If yes, then don't forget to mark this as answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem. I am looking either for a solution to undo solved changes or to disable the automatic save on datasheet view.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing is available out of the box.